# memfill / arrayfill in java? More effective way than nested loops?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know that the fastest way to copy an array in java is using the System.arraycopy()-fn. Is there something similar when i want to set all fields of the array to – lets say: – 5?

Or do i have do use nested for- or while-loops?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Use `Arrays.fill()`. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Arrays.fill uses a for loop under the covers. Its no faster than doing it yourself, though its less code.

Comment: It might be optimised in the JVM, though.

Comment: The JIT would optimize the loop, generally regardless of where it's found.